# Android: Check when app has been installed successfully

Tags: android, installation

How to check if an app in android has been installed successfully? Is there a way else than

```
private boolean isInstalled(String pack) {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    boolean app_installed = false;
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo(pack, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        app_installed = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        app_installed = false;
    }
    return app_installed;
}
```

Comment: A few clarifications may be helpful to readers: What do you mean by successfully? Is that just that it did install? Second, are you checking your own app or a different app (since there is a way to check if your app has been successfully updated)?

Comment: I want to check if my app did install. When a click on the install button, i want my code to know that the installation is done.

Comment: There is no way to determine if your app has just finished installing the first time.